# Typescript: add property to an array type

Tags: typescript

I have a type which is an array of objects:

```
type myArray = Array<{fist: string; second: string}>
```

Then I'd like to use this type but with an additional prop, say ’third`

```
interface MyInterface {
  arrayWithAdditionalProp: myArray..
}
```

But how?
This won't work:

```
(myArray & {third:string})[]
```

As myArray is already an array, not destructured. On the same token, is it possible to also remove a prop from the array?

Comment: This is a known issue discussed in [ms/TS#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874). You can't intersect the array. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5kQ9W) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks that works, I saw that @kennarddh works as well even though it's an intersection

Comment: it actually doesn't if you then try to map through the array, the element will not be the intersected one. So I encourage you to change the selected answer. The issue can be seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiCCAnRBDEUC8UmpAHgG8oAzASwGdgAuKSxUgOwHMBuWiAYwHsGATGuoyZQAvgD4AUBNCQoDCAHccaTLATIVAMihFgAC1KJ+tYPWaiA2gF0pE7g0pQUyGvKUb0WayynPEAOhgUMAAKUmAIGEwxHQkoKAB6BNj4pPiSCmoTM1Y4xOT48k4eY0FmH1TkkTzwyIkRAEogA). If you want I can write an answer explaining

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know, yes please if you have time to explain, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may seem like the solution is just to do an intersection with `&`,  in reality, it's not. The issue is described in [ms/TS#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874) and the official contributors note is:

> Array intersection is weird since there are many invariants of arrays and many invariants of intersections that can't be simultaneously met. For example, if it's valid to call a.push(x) when a is A, then it should be valid to write `ab.push(x)` when `ab` is `A & B`, but that creates an unsound read on `(A & B)[number]`.
> In higher-order the current behavior is really the best we can do; in zero-order it's really preferable to just write `Array<A & B>`, `Array<A> | Array<B>`, or `Array<A | B>` depending on which you mean to happen.

Let's observe the error with the intersection:

```
type MyArray = Array<{ fist: string; second: string }>

type NewArray = MyArray & { third: string }[]

// MyArray & {third: string;}[]
const arr: NewArray = [];

// {
//     fist: string;
//     second: string;
// } & {
//     third: string;
// }
const first = arr[0]
```

So far, so good, but let's now try to map through the `arr`:

```
arr.map(item => {
  // {
  //   fist: string;
  //   second: string;
  // }
  item
})
```

What happened? Where did the intersection go? As the official contributor mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874#issuecomment-830216728) it is a design limitation:

> It's a design limitation that the map function doesn't get reduced to a single overload

So, how we should make this work? We should create a type that returns the type of the element of the original array and create a new one using `Array<Original & Extra>` syntax.

To get the type of the element we will need to use [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword:

```
type AddFieldToArrayElement<T extends unknown[], Addition> = T extends Array<
  infer Item
>
  ? (Item & Addition)[]
  : T;
```

Usage:

```
// ({
//     fist: string;
//     second: string;
// } & {
//     third: string;
// })[]
type NewArray = AddFieldToArrayElement<MyArray, { third: string }>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEUC8UmpAHgG8oAzASwGdgAuKSxUgOwHMBuWiAYwHsGATGuoyZQAvgD4WAKEmhI2XrwBipCABteAFS440AUVUQAthAbA8GqBAAewE73JQArgwDWDLgHcGAbQC6AGnleUmBSHjFMKAtrWz4HHXxJKChGYghEKABJW0NJMSSoAH4oAApsoygAMiCQsIYASj8Cmg0pSQB6dtKCDq7k5LJKAWB6ZilO-uTyTh5+WhGhca6RKqgeicngAAtSRDnBMd7RRt8ZcGgAOQgPBMj4BWU1TW1kPQNjUzw4BMCibd39gtmKIJNIgA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword to obtain information of the array element type, and derive a new type out of it.

```
type MyNewArray = MyArray extends Array<infer T> ? Array<T & {third: string}> : never;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

You can get the array content type and merge it with other type then re create the array

```
type IMergeArray<IArray extends Array<T>, NewContent, T = unknown> = (IArray[number] & NewContent)[]

type myArray = Array<{ fist: string; second: string }>

type newArray = IMergeArray<myArray, { third: string }>

const x: newArray = [{
  fist:'1',
  second:'1',
  third: 'a',
}] // Pass

const y: newArray = [{
  fist:'1',
  second:'1',
}] // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgshATgcwgQUYghiAPDDbEKCAD2AgDsATAZykJ1wBUA+AGigDkIB3AYQD2lCiM7MoAXigBXSgGtKg3pVZSoACgKYcAbUoyAtgCMkAXSgAybnyEiqwAJS6zAKFehIUQyEbFpfrgA3lAAZgCWtMAAXFBRiOGUyADccRAAxsLUsfGJyFAAvqzuntCUfH7q8EiogT5+nCHAABbhiNlxwAlJhcWumZRRUKSx5byV0rpBrlBhkTEA5ACMC+wzaQPZy6vrLW0dC1g7BRYA9KdQAApYtLTuA0MgoxU6-lBT6xFR0dtrs7QZLI-FZrE5Qc5QACimEEiCAA)

### <s>Simpler Answer</s> Doesn't work, read `@wonderflame` answer.

Combine 2 array using `&` (Type Intersection)

```
type myArray = Array<{ fist: string; second: string }>

type newArray = myArray & { third: string }[]

const x: newArray = [{
  fist:'1',
  second:'1',
  third: 'a',
}] // Pass

const y: newArray = [{
  fist:'1',
  second:'1',
}] // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiCCAnRBDEUC8UmpAHgG8oAzASwGdgAuKSxUgOwHMBuWiAYwHsGATGuoyZQAvgD4AUBNCQoDCAHccaTLATIVAMihFgAC1KJ+tYPWaiA2gF0p3BpSgAPGvKUb0WCwQlQSFagDkAIwBADQ+7Hb8wWER+obGASixIlZQAPTpUAAKKOTktjwOIC6Kyh5QXhFklFQx4b7knDzRIeGpGVkAoshciEA)

Comment: `Simpler Answer` doesn't work and this is not what someone should try to do. Issues happen when you try to loop through the array, where the inferred type of the element is incorrect. You can see it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAtiCCAnRBDEUC8UmpAHgG8oAzASwGdgAuKSxUgOwHMBuWiAYwHsGATGuoyZQAvgD4AUBNCQoDCAHccaTLATIVAMihFgAC1KJ+tYPWaiA2gF0pE7g0pQUyGvKUb0WayynPEAOhgUMAAKUmAIGEwxHQkoKAB6BNj4pPiSCmoTM1Y4xOT48k4eY0FmH1TkkTzwyIkRAEogA)

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work. Your playground doesn't show any error?

Comment: Nevermind, I read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple approach, you can try this:

```js
(myArray[number] & {third:string})[]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the element can still change in your case do not define the type as an array but as the element, and only make it an array wherever it is required.

This way the code is still easy to read and understand.

```js
type MyElement = { fist: string; second: string };

interface MyInterface {
  arrayWithAdditionalProp: (MyElement & { third: string })[];
}
```

Of course if the extended type is used in multiple locations you can still create a second/third type:

```js
type MyExtendedElement = { fist: string; second: string } & { third: string };
type MyExtendedArray = MyExtendedElement[];
```